# From which file does Angular js execution start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular js project. I downloaded the seed project and made some changes. I am able to run it. When I start the server, i have to manually go to 
localhost:portnum/app/index.html
  to run the index.html"

How can i configure that when i type my localhost/portnum, it should redirect to index.html directly. I have gone through many angular projects. I am not able to understand where does the angular execution start. I mean, from where does the execution begin. There are lot many js files. Kindly help in this regard.

Sabarisri Subramaniyan

Comment: It starts in localhost/app/index.html, if you go to localhost/portnum it has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is not an angular's one. This is a routing problem. Which server do you use to serve angularJs application?

Comment: express server using node js

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it isn't an angular issue.  Your web server will make what ever directory you tell it to the root of your website/app. One really simple way you could handle this (this is what I do when testing on localhost):

if you have python installed use the python simple http server:

first change into your app directory:

```
cd /app
```

then run the python simple http server from inside of that directory:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

the server is smart enough to know that index.html is the first page it should load, so all you have to do now is go to your browser and type:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

done.

There are other web servers that will accomplish this same thing. the important thing to remember is that it will look inside whatever folder you designate as the root folder. By launching the python simple server while inside of the /app folder, that folder will be set as the root.  Most web servers will know that index.html is the first page of the site just from the common use of "index".

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use Routes like below

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home/default page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/page1', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/otherpage1.html',
            controller  : 'otherpage1Controller'
        })
        .when('/page2', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/otherpage2.html',
            controller  : 'otherpage2Controller'
        });
});
```

Check this Link : 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

Comment: Hi, I will add the said code to my project. But into which file? It is the place I miss. If i add this to my controller.js (say) , and include it in index.html, then how will i tell that you should run index.html ? Which will be the first running file in my project, in which i can write this routing technique. Pls explain.                    Thanks, Sabarisri Subramaniyan

Comment: Come on man, please don't expect spoon feeding or do the work for you. Just type the the same comment on google you will get enough resources .